# Label kivy does not display text in List form

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to print a list in a kivy Label but when I run the code it only shows me the first line of the list. How can I get kivy to print the entire list?

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
Import requests
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScreollView
from kivymd.uix.button import RoundFlatButton 
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.app import App

Build.load_string('''
<Page>:
    ScrollView:
        Label:
            id: label
            text: ''
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 1, 4
         MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: 'push'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':  .5, 'center_y':  .5}
                on_press: robot.problem()
'''

Class Page(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         súper(Page, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def problem(self):
        try:
            objetivo = requests.get(url=self.ids.t1.text)#textinput       
            header = dict(objetivo.headers)
            for x in header:
                self.ids.label.text = x + ' : ' + header[x]
                return self.ids.label.text
        except: 
            self.ids.label.text = '''  ERROR
            (https://www.example.com)'''
            self.ids.labe.text = 'swipe'
            Snackbar(text='         URL ERROR!').show()
            return self.ids.label.text

Class App(App):
    def build(self, **kwargs):
     self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
      H = ScreenManager()
      G = Page(mame='hello')
      H.add_widget(G)
      return H

App().run()
```

It only shows me one line of code and it should show me the full list, please help!

Answer (score 0):

one thing you will need to do is set the **max_lines** property of the label.

for example here is something I just tested as part of a .kv file

```
Label:
    size_hint_y: 5
    text: 'Experiment Notes\nnewline\n3rd line'
    max_lines: 10
```

I don't know precisely what your code is doing but you may need to add line feed characters into your text string.

another thing I recommend is while building your string use a temporary variable and then after completing any loops, assign the text property just one time.

```
things = ('one line', 'second line', '3rd line', )
my_string = '\n'.join(things)
my_label_object.text = my_string
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tried your solution but it still does not work for me, you will see when I try to print the content of a for loop it does not show me the content as a List, example: ( for x an example: self.ids.exp.text = x) That's when it should show me x in List form but instead it just shows me the first line of code :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
self.ids.label.text = dictionary['example']
```

I just converted to dictionary and printed each key to give me its value and so on